# Data types in the join expression don't match

Tags: sql

When I attempt to run this sql I get the message "data types in the join expression do not match".

```
SELECT oldtable.name, oldtable.number, newtable.number
FROM oldtable, newtable
WHERE (([oldtable].[number]=[newtable].[number]));
```

I want to compare the numbers from two tables and for all those who are the same add appropriate name.
can someone help me?

Comment: Can you show your table definitions?  Looks like the `number` field in both tables don't have the same data type from your error message.  Also I'd consider using the `join` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The preferred syntax would be to use [join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp):

```
SELECT OT.name, OT.number, NT.number
 FROM oldtable OT
  INNER JOIN newtable NT ON OT.[number] = NT.[number]
```

but as the message says the fields you perform the `JOIN` operation on must be the same type which may mean you have to perform a `convert` or `cast` operation on one or both of those columns.

Please post your table definitions so I can give a precise answer, but an example converting the values in both join columns to integers is shown below:

```
SELECT OT.name, OT.number, NT.number
  FROM oldtable OT
    INNER JOIN newtable NT ON CAST(OT.[number] AS INT) = CAST(NT.[number] AS INT)
```